# Elastic collisions with neutrinos

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

1: Do neutrinos undergo **elastic** collisions with fermions?

2: Would this imply a **variable** speed for neutrinos?

3: Can neutrinos transfer **momenta** in interactions?

Comment: *This question does not show any research effort*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Yes.** Beam neutrino experiments regularly observe events in which a single hadron appears in the detector. Such events are attributable to $Z$ exchange reactions like $\nu + p \to \nu' + p' + \pi ${*}, or $\nu + p \to \nu' + p'$ (where $p'$ is energetic enough to register in the detector). Reactions with leptonic products are *not* obvious because they could also arise from $W$ exchange reaction.
2. **Yes.** Contrary to the standard model, neutrinos are known to have mass, and thus have subluminal speeds dependent on their momentum. SuperKamiokande, SNO, KamLAND, and other experiments have conclusively shown that neutrinos mix. Work is proceeding on nailing down the full parameters of the mixing matrix.
3. **Yes.** Indeed it is obvious in the above reaction.

---

{*} This event may be elastic at the level where the neutrino interacts with a parton to form on on-shell pion from the nuclear sea. Such occurrences are called "quasi-elasitc scattering" by nuclear physicists. Alas some confusion arises because neutrino physicists reserve that phase for W exchange reaction likes $\nu_l + A \to l^- + A'$.

Comment: Also any scattering from a charged particle is inelastic due to exciting photon oscillators (photon radiation).

Comment: @Vladimir, that's the kind of comment that get's right up experimenter's noses. We're happy to ignore the IR Bremsstrahlung limit, as these events are measured as elastic to within the sensitivity of the detector.

Comment: Not only experimenters but also theorists do not care about this phenomenon whose probability is unity. What prevents us from being honest and precise? It is known since long ago that the inclusive many-particle picture corresponds to "mechanical" one. Just say it.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was wondering about, although I was also actually wondering if Neutrinos had variable speeds. I don't suppose you could point me at a paper that has these results?

Comment: I found this page, which I think covers it. http://cupp.oulu.fi/neutrino/nd-cross.html

Comment: @Vladimir: We don't bother with it for the same reason that we don't bother with relativistic corrections when working on Physics 101 problems: the simple version is true to a very good approximation and nothing is gained by being pedantically correct.

Comment: @dmckee: If you ignore the true nature of things, if you sincerely think the "mechanical" motion is elastic, then, when you want a more complete theory, you start to couple things that are already coupled. You fail and you invent "renormalizations" to get rid of most of your "coupling" effects. And to justify renormalizations you invent a very tricky "physics" that has nothing to do with reality.